# Error in R.java when create new activity

Tags: android

i am trying to insert new activity in my android application,after inserting the new activity it gives error in the R.java file,

> ```
>    String class
>    public static final int =0x7f050009;
> ```

it erase the variable name,and don't allow to update variable name. Is this problem occurs because i inserted new activity in the application,or problem is other ?

Comment: Delete R.java and clean/rebuild your project.

Comment: can you clean your project?

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` is generated by android automatically. You don't(shouldn't) write/modify it. Just delete it and then clean and build the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean you project from `Project>Clean..` and build again.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new activity and after adding it in android manifest xml file, then building an application in eclipse should re generates the R.java. 
If 'Build Automatically' enabled in eclipse, then on saving manifest file itself will trigger re generating R.java. Don't do anything in R.java its automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

if u create the different packages for your project Like Activity, Fragment,Bean.
In such case R will show in red color at setContentView method.at that time keep cursor at R and press ALT + ENTER it will show for import R.
click on it..
it will resolve your problem.